# リストにデータフレームを追加できない

Tags: python, pandas

Python3.7.6です。
リストにデータフレームを追加しようとしているのですが、str型と判断されてしまっているのかうまくいきません。
実行結果は以下のとおりです。
filesはfunc関数で読み込むときのファイルパスが入っているリストです。

```
lst = list()
for i in files:
    lst.append(func(k=files[i]))

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

strなのかを調べても、データフレームのようです。

```
In [10]: type(func(k=files[i]))
Out[10]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

リストにデータフレームをappendすることは無理なのでしょうか？
詳しい方、ご回答いただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `for i in files:` としていますので、`i` には `files` の要素(ファイルパス:文字列)が代入される事になります。なので、`lst.append(func(k=files[i]))` は `lst.append(func(k=i))` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 無事```lst.append(func(k=i))```でうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

2次元配列にしてみてはどうでしょうか？
例えばdataframe名をname_dfとします．
まずdataframeのコラムを取得します．

```
files = list(name_df.columns)
```

その後コラムを利用し配列にdataframeの要素を格納していきます．

```
lis = []
for w,i in enumerate(files):
  lis.append([])
  lis[w].append(name_df[i])
```

これでやりたいことはできますでしょうか？
いまいちやりたいことが理解できておらず，曖昧な回答かもしれません．
試してみてください

Comment: すみません，解決していたのですね．しっかり見ずに回答をしてしまいました．申し訳ないです

Comment: もし解決済みの質問でも、新しい回答はいつでも投稿することができるのであまり気にする必要はありません。ぜひ積極的に参加してみてください。